# What's the best practice for installing development versions of Python modules in Anaconda?

Tags: python, git, anaconda, distutils, conda

I am using the Anaconda python distribution on a Mac. I would like to play with the latest version of the [matplotlib source code on Github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib), make a few changes, and see how it runs. But most of the time I would simply like to use the normal version of matplotlib that comes with Anaconda Python, so I would like a way to switch back and forth easily.

The matplotlib documentation has a good description of the [branching and pull-request workflow](http://matplotlib.org/devel/gitwash/development_workflow.html), but it's not clear to me how I actually install and use the development version of matplotlib in a way that will preserve my working Python implementation.

My guess is that I want to set up an environment that contains the latest matplotlib version and it's dependencies and switch between that environment and the normal `root` environment. But when I use `python setup.py develop` to install the development version of matplotlib, it seems to install to both environments.

So, what is the best practice for working with the development version of a Python package from GitHub?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question, [`conda env`](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html) is capable of maintaining separate Python environments for development versions of whichever packages you want to work on.

---

I'm not quite sure why you are finding that `python setup.py develop` is installing the dev version of matplotlib to your `root` environment. 
Perhaps you created a new environment, but didn't activate it before installing the dev version of matplotlib? For example:

```
~$ conda create --name matplotlib-dev --clone root
Fetching package metadata: ....
src_prefix: '/home/alistair/anaconda'
dst_prefix: '/home/alistair/anaconda/envs/matplotlib-dev'
Packages: 165
Files: 32
Linking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|#####################################################| 100%
#
# To activate this environment, use:
# $ source activate matplotlib-dev
#
# To deactivate this environment, use:
# $ source deactivate
#
~$ conda info --envs 
# conda environments:
#
matplotlib-dev           /home/alistair/anaconda/envs/matplotlib-dev
root                  *  /home/alistair/anaconda
```

At this point I have created a `matplotlib-dev` environment but I haven't activated it yet, so installing any new packages would still modify my `root` environment.

```
~$ source activate matplotlib-dev
discarding /home/alistair/anaconda/bin from PATH
prepending /home/alistair/anaconda/envs/matplotlib-dev/bin to PATH

(matplotlib-dev)~$ conda info --envs 
# conda environments:
#
matplotlib-dev        *  /home/alistair/anaconda/envs/matplotlib-dev
root                     /home/alistair/anaconda
```

---

In any case, using setuptools directly (i.e. `python setup.py install` or `python setup.py develop`) is [no longer recommended](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.numeric.general/61757), and [might not be supported by future versions of numpy etc.](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6599).

The preferred method is to use `pip install <path>`, or `pip install -e <path>` if you want an ["editable"](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs) installation (similar to what `python setup.py develop` gives you):

```
(matplotlib-dev)~$ pip install -e git+git://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git#egg=matplotlib-dev
Obtaining matplotlib from git+git://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git#egg=matplotlib-dev
  Cloning git://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git to ./src/matplotlib
...
Installing collected packages: matplotlib
  Running setup.py develop for matplotlib
Successfully installed matplotlib-1.5.0+337.g595868a

(matplotlib-dev)~$ python -c "import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__)"
1.5.0.post337+g595868a

(matplotlib-dev)~$ source deactivate
discarding /home/alistair/anaconda/envs/matplotlib-dev/bin from PATH

~$ python -c "import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__)"
1.4.3
```

Note the [`#egg=` part](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support), which tells `pip` to install the source to `./src/matplotlib-dev`. Instead of a `git` URI you could also pass `pip` the path to a local source directory if you've already got a local copy that you're currently working on.

It should also be possible to use [`conda develop <path>`](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/commands/build/conda-develop.html) instead of `pip install -e <path>`, although `conda` doesn't seem to offer integrated VCS support like `pip` does.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions! I tried the "pip install -e" approach from GitHub and I think that it worked. I now realize that I should probably just not install the package, and instead specify at the top of my script using sys.path.insert which version of matplotlib to use.

Comment: I can't see much advantage to manually adding your source directory to `sys.path` over `pip install -e source_dir/` or `python source_dir/setup.py develop`. All three are basically just different ways to extend your Python path to your working source directory - the latter two do it in a persistent way by creating an `.egg-link` file in your `site-packages` directory ([see here for more details](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#development-mode)). I dislike modifying `sys.path` directly since it's relatively easy to lose track of its state and import the wrong version.

Comment: One advantage of just modifying the sys.path in a certain script is that there is no need to mess with virtual environments. When I started playing with virtual environments, this creates a bunch of weird issues with matplotlib as described here: http://matplotlib.org/1.5.0/faq/virtualenv_faq.html and I got scared.

Comment: True, but *"This problem does not exist if you use Conda environments where you can install all Conda supported GUI frameworks directly into the environment"*.

Comment: I actually do most of my work inside a regular virtualenv rather than using conda. My usual method is to create a `base` virtualenv containing numpy and other core dependencies, and install matplotlib by manually symlinking the necessary GUI libraries from  `dist-packages` ([see here](http://www.stevenmaude.co.uk/posts/installing-matplotlib-in-virtualenv), for example). I then clone from this base virtualenv whenever I start a new project that depends on matplotlib. Another method would be to create the virtualenv using virtualenvwrapper with the `--system-site-packages` flag.

Comment: When I tried to use the conda environment, I tried to import matplotlib.pyplot and got the error: "RuntimeError: Python is not installed as a framework." However, I just realized that I could call pythonw instead and then it works fine. For the record, I installed from the directory created with GitHub using "pip install -e ."